What are the reasons N₂O is not categorized as NOx?
Since nitrous oxide ($\ce{N2O}$) is also a nitrogen oxide, why isn't it classified as part of $\ce{NO_x}$? What makes only NO and $\ce{NO2}$ fall under the $\ce{NO_x}$ category but not $\ce{N2O}$?

All classifications are man-made and cannot be perfect. N2O is not toxic like NO and NO2 and environmentally benign.

@ACR It's only "environmentally benign" as long as you ignore its greenhouse effect, roughly 300 times more potent than CO₂ :-)

$\ce{NO}$ and $\ce{NO2}$ are formed as result of air ionization (natural source) and high temperature fuel-air combustion (human source) as air pollution, denoted as $\ce{NOX}$/$\ce{NOx}$.
Other nitrogen oxides do not come this way and do not directly participate on direct pollution. $\ce{N2O}$ mostly comes from natural soil processes and agriculture. Its effect is indirect as a greenhouse gas and ozone depletion cotributor.
Furthermore, $\ce{N2O}$, $\ce{N2O3}$ and $\ce{N2O5}$ have all two nitrogen atoms, not one.
So $\ce{NOx}$ does not mean any of or all nitrogen oxides.
For more, check Wikipedia - NOx, among others less used $\ce{NOy}$ and $\ce{NOz}$

$\ce{NO}$ and $\ce{NO2}$ appear usually together. $\ce{NO}$ is produced when nitric acid reacts with metals and many organic substances. But in the presence of air, $\ce{NO}$ is quicky transformed into $\ce{NO2}$ according to : $$\ce{2 NO + O2 -> 2 NO2}$$ And $\ce{NO2}$ is quickly transformed back to $\ce{NO}$ by water according to $$\ce{3 NO2 + H2O -> 1 NO + 2 HNO3}$$ So in the usual atmosphere, $\ce{NO}$ and $\ce{NO2}$ are often both simultaneously present, and they are both toxic. This why we usually speak of $\ce{NO_x}$ instead of mentioning $\ce{NO}$ and/or $\ce{NO2}$.
$\ce{N2O}$ is not included in this formalism, because $\ce{N2O}$ is not easily transformed into either $\ce{NO}$ or $\ce{NO2}$.
It should also be mentioned that, at low temperatures, $\ce{NO2}$ dimerizes and form $\ce{N2O4}$, and that $\ce{NO}$ and $\ce{NO2}$ react to form $\ce{N2O3}$. $$\ce{NO + NO2 -> N2O3}$$ $$\ce{2 NO2 ->N2O4}$$These reactions are reversible. At high enough temperature, both $\ce{N2O3}$ and $\ce{N2O4}$ are decomposed into $\ce{NO}$ and $\ce{N2O3}$

Paraphrased from Wikipedia article of NOx:

NOx is the cumulative mixture and  shorthand representative for nitric oxide ($\ce{NO}$) and nitrogen dioxide ($\ce{NO2}$), which are most relevant for air pollution. These gases contribute to the formation of smog and acid rain, as well as affecting tropospheric ozone.
NOx does not include nitrous oxide ($\ce{N2O}$) a fairly inert oxide of nitrogen that contributes less severely to air pollution, notwithstanding its involvement in ozone depletion and high global warming potential.

